# Inherit and add properties to child class

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, oop, inheritance

I can inherit from a class, and add properties to my new class... that is all good.

```
Class class1

 Property a as string

End Class

Class class2
 inherits class1

 property b as string

End Class

Dim mytest as new class2

mytest.a = "bleh"
mytest.b = "bah"
```

How do I add properties to a child class inside a class I am inheriting?

```
Class class3

 Property a as string

 Class class3_1
   Property c as string
 End Class

End Class
```

How do I create a new class that enherits class3, but add a property to class3_1, inside my new enherited class?

#### NEW EDIT WITH ACTUAL NON WORKING CODE

```
Public Class testclass

    Public Class class1

        Property x As String
        Property firstChildClass As New class1_1

        Public Class class1_1
            Property a As String
        End Class

    End Class

    Public Class inherited_class1
        Inherits class1

        Public Class class1_1  '///// Warning here to use "Shadows" keyword.. but that also does not work... takes away the warning, but still cant access property b when using a new instance of class
            Property b As String
        End Class

    End Class

    Sub test()

        Dim myTestClass As New inherited_class1

        myTestClass.firstChildClass.b = "blah" '///// This does not work...

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the containing class in the inheritance of the sub class. You have to separately inherit the containing class and the sub class:

```
Public Class inherited_class1
    Inherits class1

    Public Class class1_2
        Inherits class1_1
        Public Property b() As String
    End Class

End Class


Public Sub test()
    Dim myTestClass As New inherited_class1()

    Dim ic As New inherited_class1.class1_2()
    myTestClass.firstChildClass = ic
    ic.b = "blah"
    '''//// This does not work...
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I think we are on different pages... I want to enherit the parent class, with all its properties, as well as all the other child classes inside it... BUT, I want to make changes to "some" of the child classes that are inherited with the parent class

Comment: @LouisvanTonder: Is the update more what you'd expected to see?

Comment: @LouisvanTonder: Check the update. I am a c# programmer so I converted it from and to VB.NET. Hope it works for you.

Comment: The main problem I think was the casting between sub class and inherited sub class. You don't see the property since you reference the base sub class.

Comment: Ok, but recreating a sub class with a different name, and inhereting from within it, should work, but that leaves my final instantiation with the original (base) subclass as well as the new subclass?

Comment: Well, yes. You have two: a sub class and a derived sub class. Just classes like always.

Comment: Is that your final answer :-) ? Do I have to live with it? I was hoping to use the same technique where I can add properties to an inherited class, without -recreating anything, just adding to the original structure

Comment: No, sorry. Nothing you can do about it... :(